# Will disabling JavaScript affect PHP sessions?

Tags: php, javascript

Will there be any effect on PHP Session in case of disabling Javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

You're Welcome

Brandon

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, **no**.

Disabling cookies can affect PHP session, but it's possible to workaround it.

Answer (score 0):

No, PHP sessions are read/written to the cookies that are sent via the headers in an HTTP request. Javascript plays no part in this(unless your JS code is manipulating the session data, however I highly doubt you are doing this).

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using ajax, no, if you are, perhaps (if your application is well-designed, it shouldn´t).

Answer (score -1):

That really depends on your application. If you mess with the session cookie in JS in your app, then yes, the PHP session will be affected.

You're almost certainly not doing this, however, so you should be fine.